# distribution of the last arrival in poisson process

Tags: poisson-process

Consider a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$ and let $L$ be the time of the last arrival in the interval $[0,t]$, with $L=0$ if there was no arrival.

How can I prove that t-L has exponential distribution with rat $\lambda$?
I tried to prove it by the following relation
\begin{equation}
P(t-L>x)=P(N(x)=0)
\end{equation}
However it leads us to a correct answer but I think this relation can not be true. because $P(N(x))=0$ doesn't have any information about t!
Actually we know that $t-L>x$ means that $N(x)=0$ but the reverse is not obvious.So all we can say is: 
$P(t-L>x)<=P(N(x)=0)$.
The purpose of this discussion is to find $E[t-L]$ by the knowledge of distribution of $L$ or $t-L$!

Comment: I seem to remember an answer that Did (a very high-reputation user on math.SE) posted on math.SE to the effect that while the time of the _next_ arrival after any given time $t_0$ is indeed exponentially distributed, the time of the _most recent_ arrival before $t_0$ is _not_ exponentially distributed. But I don't seem to be able to find that answer now.

Comment: The answer referred to in my comment above might be [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/426986/15941) where the time elapsed since the last arrival is claimed to be of the form $\min(t,X)$ where $X$ is an exponential random variable with parameter $\lambda$ (while as everyone knows and agrees that the time till the next arrival after $t$ is exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Professor (Dr.Pasha) has guided me to solve the problem as follows:
Theorem 2.14.(Richard Durrett) If we condition on N(t), then  $T_1,T_2,..,T_n$ have uniform distribution in [0,t].
 thus $P(\max \{T_1,...,T_n\}<s)=\frac{s^n}{t^n}$ 
so $E[L|N(t)=n]=\frac{nt}{n+1}$

$E [L] 
= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} E [ L \,| \, N(t) = n ] \, P \{ N(t)=n \}
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} E [\max \{T_1,...,T_n\}\,| \, N(t) = n ] \, P \{ N(t)=n \}
= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n t}{n+1} \, P \{ N(t)=n \}
= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{n+1} \right) t \, \frac{ (\lambda t)^n}{n!} e^{-\lambda t}
= t e^{- \lambda t} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(\lambda t)^n}{n!} - t e^{- \lambda t} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n+1} \frac{ ( \lambda t)^n}{n!}.$\

Now after a little computation you find that

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n+1} \frac{ ( \lambda t)^n}{n!} = \frac{1}{ \lambda t} ( e^{ \lambda t} - 1 ).$\

Thus

$E [ L ] = t - t e^{- \lambda t} \frac{1}{\lambda t} ( e^{ \lambda t} - 1 ) = t - \frac{1}{\lambda } (1 - e^{ \lambda t} ).$

Therefore we indeed obtain

$E [ t - L ] = t - E [ L ] = t - \left( t - \frac{1}{\lambda } (1 - e^{ \lambda t} ) \right) = \frac{1}{\lambda } (1 - e^{ \lambda t} ).$

Comment: So what was wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Let us define a random variable T=t-L

$P(T<x)$
$\\=1-P(\text{no arrival happened in the interval } [t-x, t])$
$\\= 1-P(\text{no arrival happened in the interval } [0, x])$
$\\= 1-\frac{\lambda^0}{0!} \exp{(-\lambda x)}$
$\\= 1-\exp{(-\lambda x)}$

This is the cdf of the exponential distribution.

Comment: Consider the case that  there is an arrival between L and t-x but there is no.arrival between t-x and t. So your first equality is not true!

Comment: What do you mean there is an arrival between L and t-x? Wasn't L defined as the last arrival?

Comment: what you said is: $P(t-L>x)=P(no~ arrival~ in ~[t-x,t])$. we know that if $A\Rightarrow B$ then $P(A)\le P(B)$.in our discussion we know that $t-L>x\Rightarrow no~ arrival ~in~ [t-x, t]$ so $P(t-L>x)\le P(no~ arrival ~in [t-x,t])$ but $no ~arrival ~in [t-x,t]$  doesn't mean $t-L>x$ or equivalently $L<t-x$. I mean the reverse is not true.

Comment: That is not true what you said. P(t-L > x) only says about what happens in the subinterval [t-x, t]. The second implication holds too.

Comment: x is bounded. The last period T does not follow exponential distribution, because the period between L and next arrive will be the exponential distribution, and T is always less than this period.